# Recursively remove a user from a filesystem

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-permissions

I mounted an external NTFS HDD and now I got file permission issues with this unknown user called `S-1-5-21-2636111369-1034528402-601712504-500`. I want to remove this user recursively from all files on the external HDD. How can I achieve this? I tried the following `icacls` query but I failed miserably:

```
icacls F: /remove:g S-1-5-21-2636111369-1034528402-601712504-500 /T
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The numerical SID needs to be `*` prefixed.

```
icacls F:\ /remove:g *S-1-5-21-2636111369-1034528402-601712504-500 /T
```